# Angularjs testing - Initialize controller with binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a controller like this.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
let ctrl = this;

if (ctrl.contract) {
    ctrl.contract.typeId = ctrl.contract.type.id;
} else {
    ctrl.contract = {
        name: 'test'
    };
}
....
```

It can either have, or not have `contract` bound to it.
Problem arises in my test

```
describe('MyCtrl', () => {
let ctrl;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mymodule'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));

describe('Update contract', () => {
    beforeEach(inject((_$controller_) => {
        ctrl = _$controller_('MyCtrl', {}, {
            contract: {
                type: {
                    id: 2
                }
            }
        });
    }));

    it('should set the contract.typeId to be the id of the type of the contract that was sent in', () => {
        expect(ctrl.contract.typeId).toBe(ctrl.contract.type.id);
    });
})
});
```

I pass in a contract object, which means it should go into the first `if` in my controller and set the `typeId`.
But it always goes into the `else` no matter what I do.

How can I make sure the controller don't run or start before all my variables are bound to it?

Comment: How are you passing `contract` to your controller? I was expecting to see something like `app.controller('MyCtrl', function(contract) {`

Comment: I am angularjs material $mdDialog bindToController

Comment: If you add a `console.log(ctrl.contract);` in your controller, what do you get when running the test?

Comment: I get `undefined`

Comment: I think that helps us pinpoint the problem to the code instantiating the controller, in your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you need to get the $controller service directly and also pass a valid scope (not an empty object)

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
    }, {
        contract: {
            type: {
                id: 2
            }
        }
    });
}));
```